# Paging: Storing Search Results

Tags: search, paging

What's the proper way to deal with a web page that returns results of a search that could have differing results from one moment to another?

I.e. returning the query the first time could contain different results from when the user clicks on page 2, and running the query again.

How do most people deal with this scenario?  Generally I'm working with internal ASP.Net applications (where security/bandwidth aren't huge concerns), so I'll store the results in the ViewState, and on postbacks deal with that data opposed to querying the database.

What's the proper methodology for external WWW use?  My best guess is to store the results in a temporary database table (not literally a temp table; I guess 'staging' might be more accurate), but I would think that table would get hammered quite a bit with inserts/deletes/etc, and I would think you'd need a process to clean the table up, which doesn't seem like a very elegant solution.

Am I anywhere close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most applications don't deal with it... they assume the results won't change enough to warrant some sort of caching mechanism. However, if you're working with highly-realtime data (like Twitter results, for instance), your paging links would most likely look like this:

`?q=your+query&olderthan={last result shown}&limit=10`

...where `{last result shown}` is the ID of the last result on the current page. This ID would be used to allow you to query for results older than the specified ID: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < {last result shown}`.

Comment: I've seen this many times and it's a valid solution , but won't work if you want or need to use POST vs. GET. Also this requires handling of security in your app - otherwise sombody can change URL to limit = 200000 - and if you are displaying a list of products let's say - you can get your server hammered and browser frozen :-)

Comment: This method would work just fine with POST requests. Just slip it in `<input type="hidden" name="olderthan" value="0" />`. And about bounding the limit... I thought that went without saying ;)

Comment: I like the 'olderthan' concept.  The querystring can be validated against what you'll allow, or the values could be stored in the viewstate

Answer (score 1):

Although it can be very memory intensive, you could also consider storing the search results into the session and paging through the session rather than running a query each time.

Answer (score 1):

How about a session? This is temp data specific to a session, so why not use session?

I haven't done asp in ages ( from before the .NET era :-) ) , but in PHP or rails you would use sessions for any temporary store like. You can use either local file system ( on the server) or DB as a session store. There are ways to optimize, so I wouldn't worry about DB being hammered, unless you have thousands of users. Also DBs are designed to handle thousands of inserts and deletions - any major DB - SQL server, MySQL, PostgreSQL shouldn't have any problem with it.